# Mean of date interval in lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

How do you get the 'mean' (or more accurately the midpoint) of a lubridate interval object? I've tried using the base mean() function but that return back a double.

```
library(lubridate)   
ex = interval(ymd("2009-05-01"), ymd("2009-07-01"))
mean(ex)
[1] 5270400
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to just add to the starting date the half of the duration of `interval`. Try out:

```
ex@start + as.duration(ex)/2
[1] "2009-05-31 12:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Disappointed there isn't a built in function for this, but this seems like the least verbose way get the mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `int_start()` and `int_end()` functions to calculate the midpoint of an interval:

```
library(lubridate)
int_start(ex) + (int_end(ex) - int_start(ex))/2
[1] "2009-05-31 12:00:00 UTC"
```

You could make this into a simple function for simplicity:

```
int_midpoint <- function(interval) {
    int_start(interval) + (int_end(interval) - int_start(interval))/2
}

int_midpoint(ex)
[1] "2009-05-31 12:00:00 UTC"
```

This function will also work with `lapply` (though not `sapply`) on a vector:

```
lapply(c(ex, ex), int_midpoint)
[[1]]
[1] "2009-05-31 12:00:00 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "2009-05-31 12:00:00 UTC"
```